# How to add more links in my menu

Tags: html, css

I'd like to improve my css menu for example when I add new links there is a lag. I would like added 8 links if possible. How to avoid this? I would like that the links are right.

```css
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #BEBEBE;
}

.header {
  background-color: #1A5694;
  width: 810px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.headerconnexion {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 13px 13px 0px 0px;
}

.headerconnexion a {
  color: #B3D1FA;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 13px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="index.php">
    <img class="logo" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/08/1456571967-facebook-logo-png-transparent-background.png" />
  </a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Link toast</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Link toast</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Link toast</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Link toast</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Link toast</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Link toast</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Link toast</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Link toast</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

**[Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Serg78/k7tx14e9/)**

Comment: What do you mean by `lag`?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `width` for `nav`

```
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/k7tx14e9/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have resposive menu like Bootstrap ,.... 
you should be using percent(%) and (em) in your css.

and for samrt phone and small device you should be using (media query) if you want to have nice menu.
By the way , for your code :

```
nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```